# Estoy Configuration Un Boton buscar de mi Formulario Cliente y tengo un Problemas Con una Variable

Tags: c#

Hola Chicos saludos soy Novato en esto y estoy realizando un Peque;o Proyercto final de Grado sobre un Consultorio Medico.

```
private void btnbuscar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuscarUsuario bc = new BuscarUsuario();
        bc.Show();
        if (bc.ClienteSelecionado != null)
        {
            txtnombre.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.nombre;
            txtapellido.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.apellido;
            txtiduser.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.user;
            txtpass.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.contraseña;
            txttel.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.tel;
            txtpais.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.pais;
            txtsexo.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.sexo;
            txtcedula.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.cedula;
            txtedad.Text = Ibc.ClienteSelecionado.edad;
            txtdir.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.dir;
```

Este es el codigo en la cadena txtedad Me sale un error diciendome que no Se puede convertir iplicitamente un int en String , Necesito saber que tengo que poner , Espero , que me puedan ayudar , cualquier ayuda se lo agradeseria mucho

Comment: `variable.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

Explicitamente puedes convertir un entero a cadena como por ejemplo:

```
txtedad.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.edad.ToString();
```

pero si no tienes un valor allí te va a generar otro error. Verifica si te devuelve valor todas las propiedades de BuscarUsuario,

Comment: Gracias Amigo Me funciono Exelente aporte

Comment: @CasperIOrtegaMelendez si te ha funcionado, considera aceptar la respuesta (el check que está al lado de la misma) para que otros sepan que es la respuesta correcta. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertirlo así (Ambas funcionan):

```
txtedad.Text = bc.ClienteSelecionado.edad.ToString();

txtedad.Text = Convert.ToString(bc.ClienteSelecionado.edad);
```

> Al igual puedes revisar la documentación de la [Clase Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) , para que mires todos los tipos de datos que puedes convertir.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad Text de las cajas de Texto reciben String por ello debes en forma explicita convertir los int a String para poder colocarlo en la propiedad Text

Alternativa 1:

```
txtedad.Text = Ibc.ClienteSelecionado.edad.ToString();
```

ToString(), convierte Ibc.ClienteSelecionado.edad a su equivalente en string. Esto puede generar una exepcion del tipo NullReferenceException si el valor de la edad es null

Alternativa 2:

```
txtedad.Text = Convert.ToString(Ibc.ClienteSelecionado.edad);
```

Si el valor de Ibc.ClienteSelecionado.edad es null, no generar error sino que se mostrara null.

Alternativa 3:

```
txtedad.Text = (String)Ibc.ClienteSelecionado.edad;
```

(String) aqui aaplicamos un cast en runtime.